# Why is my padding only showing when the element is in the hover state?

Tags: html, css

I have just started to learn html and css. I have ran into this issue while coding. The padding of the list items only become visible when it's in the hover state. 
I want it to appear all the time.

I have tried and managed to produce the following code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navbar {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
}

#g {
  display: flex;
}

#g li {
  list-style: none;
}

#g li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

#g li a:hover {
  background: red;
}

#g li:first-child {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <ul id="g">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Try to set `display:block` on `#g li a `

Comment: Your li is flex elements with a flex parent so By default  is flex: 0 1 auto.

Answer (score 0):

Since, anchor tags are always display: inline by default, set the `<a>` itself to a proper block container type such as block or inline-block for its layout to work as intended.

```
#g li a {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using display: flex; property to your nchor tag:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navbar {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
}

#g {
  display: flex;
}

#g li {
  list-style: none;
}

#g li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
}

#g li a:hover {
  background: red;
}

#g li:first-child {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <ul id="g">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait what you're asking?

> Why is my padding only showing when the element is in the hover state?

Because you deliberately set the background to only show when in the hover state:

```css
#g li a:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

But, if your question is why it appears so weird, why it doesn't push the top and bottom border away, then because the `padding` you set is to the `a` tag, which is `display: inline` (by default), and what you're seeing is the default behavior for display: inline element. According to: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp

> Compared to `display: inline`, the major difference is that `display: inline-block` allows to set a width and height on the element.
>
> Also, **with `display: inline-block`, the `top and bottom` margins/paddings are respected, but with `display: inline` they are not**.

Try the example below to see difference between `display: inline`, `display: inline-block` and `display: block`:

```css
span.a {
  display: inline; /* the default for span */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid blue;  
  background-color: yellow; 
}

span.b {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid blue;    
  background-color: yellow; 
}

span.c {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid blue;    
  background-color: yellow; 
}
```

```html
<h2>display: inline</h2>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum consequat scelerisque elit sit amet consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. <span class="a">Aliquam</span> <span class="a">venenatis</span> gravida nisl sit amet facilisis. Nullam cursus fermentum velit sed laoreet. </div>

<h2>display: inline-block</h2>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum consequat scelerisque elit sit amet consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. <span class="b">Aliquam</span> <span class="b">venenatis</span> gravida nisl sit amet facilisis. Nullam cursus fermentum velit sed laoreet. </div>

<h2>display: block</h2>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum consequat scelerisque elit sit amet consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. <span class="c">Aliquam</span> <span class="c">venenatis</span> gravida nisl sit amet facilisis. Nullam cursus fermentum velit sed laoreet. </div>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
}

.g {
  display: flex;
}

.g li {
  list-style: none;
}

.g li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.g li a:hover {
  background: red;
}

.g li:first-child {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="g">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<hr>

<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="g">
    <li><a style="display:inline-block" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a style="display:inline-block" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a style="display:inline-block" href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a style="display:inline-block" href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<hr>

<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="g">
    <li><a style="display:block" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a style="display:block" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a style="display:block" href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a style="display:block" href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```